# How do I define an associative array as a function param using zsh?

Tags: arrays, zsh, associative-array

I'm using zsh 5.8.1 with mac OS Ventura and I'm trying this:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

typeset -A foo=(
    [apple]="red"
    [banana]="yellow"
)

echo $foo[apple] # Ok! prints "red"

function foobar () {
    echo $1 # logs "foo"
    local -A bar=$1 # Error! inconsistent type for assignment
    echo $bar[apple]
}

foobar foo
```

but I'm getting this error:

> foobar:local:2: bar: inconsistent type for assignment

I have tried some things without success:

- changed `foobar foo` to `foobar $foo`, same error
- changed `local -A bar=$1` to `declare -A bar=$1`, same error

What can I do?

Comment: You can not pass an array as parameter. Parameters are always scalars. You can however pass the name of the an array as parameter, and access the array via the name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use indirect parameter expansion. Since `bar` contains the name `foo`, then `${(P)bar}` is equivalent to `$foo`. This means you can then index `${(P)bar}` the same way you would `$foo`.

```
% print ${${(P)bar}[apple]}
red
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I dived into [zsh parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) (`man zshexpn`) and this worked for me:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

typeset -A foo=(
    [apple]="red"
    [banana]="yellow"
)

function foobar () {
    # Expand the contents of 1 into a new associative array
    typeset -A bar=(${(@Pkv)1})

    # Add new item
    bar[berry]="purple"

    for key value in ${(@kv)bar}; do
        # Print all 3 fruits and its colors
        echo "$key=$value"
    done

    # Replace global foo
    eval "typeset -gA $1=(${(@kv)bar})"
}

foobar foo
echo $foo[berry] # purple
```

the key being `${(@Pkv)1}` which seems to expand the contents of the param `1` into a **new** associative array. The type can be confirmed using the `t` expansion `${(t)var}`:

```bash
echo ${(t)${(@Pkv)1}} # association
```

this new associative array can be assigned to a variable:

```bash
typeset -A bar=(${(@Pkv)1})
```

if this new association is altered and those changes need to be preserved override the original variable:

```bash
eval "typeset -gA $1=(${(@kv)bar})"
```

I don't now much about zsh or zsh best practices so suggestions are welcome!